# python scrapy css selector name extract not working

Tags: python, scrapy

i am trying to extract college names from http://www.bschool.careers360.com/search/all/bangalore using css selectors but data is not extracting. "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False" is set. after changes my code is as below. but the results remains the same

```
import scrapy

class BloreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blore'
    start_urls = ['http://www.engineering.careers360.com/search/college/bangalore']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.title'):
            yield {
                'author': quote.xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.pager-next a::attr("href")').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

And the log is

```
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.1 started (bot: google)
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_URI': 'item.csv',
 'BOT_NAME': 'google', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'google.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv
', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['google.spiders']}
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET http://www.engineering.ca
reers360.com/search/college/bangalore> (referer: None)
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <403 http://www.engineerin
g.careers360.com/search/college/bangalore>: HTTP status code is not handled or n
ot allowed
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 252,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2473,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 6, 19, 47, 644833),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 6, 19, 47, 403819)}
2016-11-02 11:49:47 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath needs to be relative your your `quote` node, in other words you need to add `.` before `//`.

Try this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.title'):
        yield {
            #'author': quote.xpath('//a/text()').extract_first(),
            #                       ^
            'author': quote.xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first(),
        }

    next_page = response.css('li.pager-next a::attr("href")').extract_first()
    # if next_page is not None:
    if next_page:  # you can also just do this
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Edit: Looking at your provided log seems like you get 404 when trying to retrieve robots.txt. Try setting `ROBOTS_TXT_OBEY = False` in `settings.py`

Comment: @punithbm yeah, I saw your log below. Seems like you are getting `404` either you are banned or that's because you are following site's robots.txt. See my edit for how to avoid this.

Comment: `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` is set, but no change in result

Comment: @punithbm you are probably banned by the website, I have it working perfectly fine, but you can post your whole spider or try using some proxy.